# Send an email for a particular column of a list sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to figure out  how to send an email for a particular column of a sharepoint online list which is created. When the SAVE button is pressed, it should send out an email. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need there is to use a workflow (or MS Flow if you have the subscription for it).

To create a workflow you will need sharepoint designer. Connect to the site collection, go to Lists and libraries, your list and then you will see workflows. Creating a new workflow will allow you to use simple logic to send emails. I'll show you an example ->

[image]

If you can use MS Flow i strongly suggest you do. Its a bit messy since they're still developing it, but its more future-proof.

[image]

Comment: wanted to create a workflow with email table, can you please help me with that.

Comment: this is the question --https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247056/send-an-email-for-a-particular-column-of-a-list-sharepoint-online